# Stop Animating Custom News list ticker on hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am doing this custom news ticker (cant afford to plug a new plugin for this :-( ) and most of it is done, the only thing which I need to stop the ticker on mouseHover and resume animation on mouseOut..

http://jsfiddle.net/Sullan/EMcMz/4/

This is the function which I am using

```
function tick(){
$('#bigWinners li:first').animate({'left':-150}, 200, function () { $(this).appendTo($('#bigWinners')).css('left', 0); });
}
setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 4000);
```

Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use the clearInterval() when you mouseenter and restart the timer when you mouseout

```
var timer = setInterval(tick, 1000);

$('#bigWinners').on({ //<-- change depending on which elements you want these to trigger on
  mouseenter: function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
  },
  mouseleave: function(){
    timer = setInterval(tick, 1000);
  }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/zQHUY/)

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

http://jsbin.com/ifokak/4/edit

```
var intv;    
function tick(){     
  intv = setInterval(function(){
    $('#bigWinners li:first').animate({left:-150}, 200, function() {
        $(this).appendTo('#bigWinners').css('left', 0);
    });
  },2000);     
}   
tick(); // initial kick

$('.mini-carousel').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
  var mEnt = e.type=='mouseenter' ? clearInterval(intv) : tick() ;
});
```

BTW use `.appendTo('#bigWinners')` instead of `.appendTo( $('#bigWinners') )`